# Need to upload an HTML file and display contents of DIV and nothing else

Tags: file-uploads, html, strip-html

I have a case in which a client needs to be able to upload a JS and an HTML file to be displayed on a page via file upload fields.

The problem is that the HTML file that is delivered to the client is a full HTML file with headers, meta, styling.

I need to be able to have the client upload the full HTML file as they receive it, but pull out only the contents of a particular DIV to be displayed within the template/page.

```
<div class="CherryPickedHTMLWrapper">
```

How would I approach this scenario?

Comment: I know it would be easy enough to do this via an iframe. Just wondering if there is a cleaner way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to accomplish, but if you have a saved *.html* file on your site (via custom file upload or however you need) and want to display just the *CherryPickedHTMLWrapper* div, then the simplest option may be to load it via JQuery's `.load()` method: [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/). This method can load a local file into an element on your page, and you can even specify a page fragment, like so:

```
$('.result').load('uploads/test.html .CherryPickedHTMLWrapper');
```

If you prefer to do it server side, you would likely want to create a custom plugin to read in the file and parse the DOM to get the element you need. There are some tools to make this easier, such as [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Client has licensed commercial financial calculators that are updated quarterly, but they come as an HTML and a JS file. The HTML file has embedded CSS and other bloat that we don't need. Just want the div that the calculators are in.

I think either of these solutions will work great, thanks!